# Faulty plot of logarithmic function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to plot a log function,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->,>=latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [below]  {$x$};
    \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [left]  {$y$};
    \clip (-2,-3) rectangle (5,3);
    \draw [very thick,blue,domain=0.01:4.5,smooth] plot (\x, {ln(\x)});
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this wavy behaviour of the blue line:

[image: Imgur]

Can you notice it?

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If you do not already know it, you should look into `PGFplots`. It works with(on top of) `TikZ`, and meets all your plotting needs.

Answer (score 27):

The `plot` function uses 25 samples by default, evenly distributed for the x values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [below]  {$x$};
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [left]  {$y$};
  \clip (-2,-3) rectangle (5,3);
  \draw [very thick,
         blue,
         domain=0.01:4.5,
         smooth,
         samples=25,% default 
         variable=\x,
  ] plot[mark=x] (\x, {ln(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with 25 samples and marks]

As can be seen, the function needs a lot higher density of samples near the y axis, one way is to increase the number of samples, the plot is using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [below]  {$x$};  
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [left]  {$y$};  
  \clip (-2,-3) rectangle (5,3);  
  \draw [very thick,
         blue,
         domain=0.01:4.5,
         smooth,
         samples=100,
         mark=x,
  ] plot (\x, {ln(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with 100 samples and marks]

Another way is to rewrite the form to a parameterized form. Then the `plot` function uses the parameter to get better distributed samples. The next example replaces x by t squared (also the values of option `domain` needs a transformation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [below]  {$x$};
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [left]  {$y$};
  \clip (-2,-3) rectangle (5,3);
  \draw [very thick,
         blue,
         domain=sqrt(0.01):sqrt(4.5),
         smooth,
         samples=25,
         variable=\t,
  ] plot[mark=x] (\t*\t, {ln(\t*\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with quadratic parameter and 25 samples]

Finally both methods can be combined to get a smooth curve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->,>=latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [below]  {$x$};
  \draw [->,>=latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node [left]  {$y$};
  \clip (-2,-3) rectangle (5,3);
  \draw [very thick,
         blue,
         domain=sqrt(0.01):sqrt(4.5),
         smooth,
         samples=100,
         variable=\t,
  ] plot (\t*\t, {ln(\t*\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with both methods]

Answer (score 12):

Here is a `pgfplots` addition for academic purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
         axis lines=middle,
         xmin=-2,xmax=5,
         ymin=-3,ymax=3,
         ticks=none
  ]
  \addplot[very thick,blue,domain=0.01:4.5,smooth,samples=100] {ln(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[SOLVED] Adding more samples, it figured out

```
\draw [very thick,blue,domain=0.01:4.5,smooth,samples=500] plot (\x, {-ln(\x)});
```

Comment: 150 samples seems to be a good minimum

Answer (score 1):

Also for academic purposes, the `mfpic`-way of tackling this. Its `\function` macro takes a subdivision length as (third) argument, here 0.01, rather than the number of samples.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost, clip]{mfpic}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-2}{5}{-3}{3}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \draw[blue]\function{0.01, \xmax, 0.01}{ln x}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be processed with LaTeX, then MetaPost, and then LaTeX again. Output:

[image]